# How can I use a javascript function in index.html

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm working on a react.js website where I'm supposed to call a javascript function in index.html. I'm experiencing some difficulties in calling the function.

This is what I'm doing in index.html

```
<head>
<script>
const getVar = getVarFromJs()
</script>
</head>
```

but whenever I do this, I get an error saying getVarFromJs is not defined. I also tried importing the function then I get an error saying "cannot use statement outside a module".

This is my js file:

```
let var = {};
export function getVarFromJs()
{return var;}

When I change the script type to module in index.html, I get this error:
Failed to load module script: Expected a Javascript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

Comment: `<script type="module"> .... </script>` to use ES modules ....

Comment: That gives me another error: "Failed to load module script: Expected a Javascript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

Comment: okay, please check this [e.g. from docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules#applying_the_module_to_your_html)